# nativescript 2.5 blank template error

Tags: nativescript

I have just updated to NativeScript 2.5
I have created a new blank project using tns-template-blank:

> $ tns create BlankProject --template tns-template-blank
>   ......
>  Project BlankProject was successfully created.

When I try to run it, I get an error:

> $ cd BlankProject
>  $ tns run ios --emulator
>
> We have failed to check if we need to add a compatability
>   LaunchScreen.xib due to: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory,
>   open
>   '/Users/joseanquiles/MyProjects/Nativescript/BlankProject/app/App_Resources/iOS/Info.plist'
>   ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir
>   '/Users/joseanquiles/MyProjects/Nativescript/BlankProject/platforms/ios/BlankProject/Resources'

However, if I create a new project using default template (without --template option), it run ok in iOS emulator.

Before, with NativeScript 2.4.2, it run perfectly, using blank template.

Is there a problem with blank template and 2.5 ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Android build also fails: :processF0DebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processF0DebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/local/opt/android-sdk/build-tools/25.0.2/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (for an iOS build) using both the tns-template-tab-navigation and the tns-template-master-detail and i noticed that a folder (and its contents) were missing from the app folder... the missing folder is called App_Resources.....

To fix the problem I just found a previous project that i had built with the default template (I think...) and copied the App_Resources folder across into the failing app folder.

My guess is that only a couple of the templates actually build the App_resources folder correctly but once you have copied the folder across from a successful build it 'should' work OK

Cheers
Ian

Comment: Thank you Ian. That is the problem! I have copied App_Resources from another project (created with the blank templeta) and now It works!